# URIError: malformed URI sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping, uri

The below code error's out with `URIError: malformed URI sequence?` when there is a `%` sign like `60% - Completed` in the URL string from where I need to extract the parameter value e.g. `http://some-external-server.com/info?progress=60%%20-%20Completed`

```
   <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            function getParameterByName(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
                return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
    </SCRIPT>
```

I dont have control of the server and need to process the output in my html page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript decodeURI(Component) malformed uri exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064536/javascript-decodeuricomponent-malformed-uri-exception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does decodeURIComponent('%') lock up my browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449588/why-does-decodeuricomponent-lock-up-my-browser)

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to URI encode the percentage sign as '%25'

```
http://some-external-server.com/info?progress=60%25%20-%20Completed
```

[EDIT]

I guess you could do something like this:

```
var str = "60%%20-%20completed";
var uri_encoded = str.replace(/%([^\d].)/, "%25$1");
console.log(str); // "60%25%20-%20completed"
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(uri_encoded);
console.log(decoded); // "60% - completed"
```

Comment: As mentioned above  - I dont have control of the server and need to process the output in my html page.

Comment: You may not be able to use decodeURIComponent then, or you may need to preprocess the url before passing it to that function. Are spaces the only other special character you can expect in the url?

Comment: No, there could be other special characters in the URL. Anything which would let me extract parameter value in this condition?

Comment: I tried to use this on the `getParameterByName` function but can't seem to get it working. Can you provide an example in the above code's context for a newbie.

Comment: Here is the code : `<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> function getParameterByName(name) { name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]"); var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), results = regex.exec(location.search); var uri_encoded = results[1].replace(/%([^\d].)/, "%25$1"); return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(uri_encoded.replace(/\+/g, " ")); } </SCRIPT>`

Comment: `TypeError: results is null` on line `var uri_encoded = results[1].replace(/%([^\d].)/, "%25$1");`.

Comment: the value of results is null. you need to check for this before the line `var uri_encoded = ...`