# Node.JS: How To Use A Percent Sign In A URL Request?

Tags: node.js, api, magento, request

I am trying to request a simple API search from Magento2, but apparently I cannot use the % sign inside the URL request. Is there another way to use the percentage sign inside the URL?

- *The %_% is after [value]*

**Request Link:**

```
const request_data = {
    url: 'http://.../rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0]'+
    '[field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%Example%'+
    '&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like',
    method: 'GET',
};
```

**Console Error:**

> URIError: URI malformed
>
> ```
> at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
> at OAuth.deParam (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:227:27)
> at OAuth.deParamUrl (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:245:17)
> at OAuth.getParameterString (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:142:132)
> at OAuth.getBaseString (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:124:130)
> at OAuth.getSignature (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:100:36)
> at OAuth.authorize (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/node_modules/oauth-1.0a/oauth-1.0a.js:87:39)
> at Object.module.exports.init (/Users/Kevin/Desktop/TestingModules/test.js:36:43)
> at [eval]:1:19
> at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
> ```

Comment: Check **Ilia Rostovtsev's** answer in this thread => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449588/why-does-decodeuricomponent-lock-up-my-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Issue**

The `%` character is escape character for urls and is the first character for url-encoding special characters in urls—it denotes the beginning of an encoded character (composed of a `%` followed by two hexadecimal characters). The reason you are getting the URIError is because when the uri is parsed, the machine sees the `%` and then looks at the next two characters to tell what character is being encoded. So `%Ex` is mistaken for the encoding of a character (but x is not a hexadecimal character so you get a malformed URI). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding or https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt for more.

**The Solution**

To encode a percent sign, replace the `%` with `%25`, which is the encoding for the percent sign.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Henry